# Question about the definition of strings that GNFA's accept

Tags: automata, finite-automata

In Sipser's "Introduction to the Theory of Computation" it states "A GNFA accepts a string $w$ in $Σ^{*}$ if $w = w_1 w_2 · · · w_k$ , where each $w_i$ is in $Σ^{*}$".

However, wouldn't a more precise definition be "A GNFA accepts a string $w$ in $Σ^{*}$ if $w = w_1 w_2 · · · w_k$ , where each $w_i$ is in $Σ$" ?

Comment: You only quote part of the definition. Please give the full one; it may be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a **GNFA** $A$ reconizes $\Sigma^{*}$, then $\epsilon \in \Sigma^{*}$ must be accepted. However $\epsilon \not\in \Sigma $.

Comment: WIth $k=0$ the proposed alternate definition admits $\varepsilon$ as well.

Comment: How would it be true if the alphabet must contain a symbol? Or are you saying that it would be vacuously true?